# How to call a javascript cookie in servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I have tried getting cookie from javascript to servlet using

> request.getcookie()

method. But I found the value as null.

Is there any way to get a cookie from javascript to servlet?

Comment: Try this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/GetCookiefromRequest.htm

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();


for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    Cookie c = cookies[i];
     c.getName()  //cookie name
    c.getValue()   //cookie value

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Cookie c : request.getCookies()) {
   if("myCookieName".equals(c.getName()) {
     System.out.println(c.getValue());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
if(cookie != null && cookie.length > 0) {
    System.out.println("CkInfo");
    for(int i = 0;i < cookie.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println("["+i+"] info");
    System.out.println("Name: "+cookie[i].getName());
    System.out.println("Comment: "+cookie[i].getComment());
    System.out.println("Domain: "+cookie[i].getDomain());
    System.out.println("MaxAge: "+cookie[i].getMaxAge());
    System.out.println("Path: "+cookie[i].getPath());
    System.out.println("Value: "+cookie[i].getValue());
    }
}
```